# find pattern 'ds***' in a string using re

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple strings starting with ds.

For eg.

```
ds000002_R2.0.2_raw.zip
ds000002_R2.0.3_raw.zip
ds000002_R2.0.4_raw.zip
ds000002_R2.0.5_raw.zip
ds000003_R2.0.0_raw.tgz
ds000003_R2.0.1_raw.tgz
ds002_raw_checksums.txt
ds003_models.tgz
ds113c_R1.0.0_sub-18.tgz
ds113c_R1.0.0_sub-20.tgz
ds113c_R1.0.0_sub-21.tgz
ds113b_raw.tgz
```

How can I extract only numbers in front of `ds***`.

So ideal output should be, `000002, 000005, 003, 002, 113b, 113c` etc

Edit: I would like to get the alphabet too after if there is any between after `ds` and before `_` or `.file_extension`

Comment: So you want the numbers between `ds` and `_` right?

Comment: @SumnerEvans yes true. But attimes that `_` might be missing. There might be directly `.tgz`or any file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(?mi)(?<=^ds)([a-z0-9])+` to match any numbers or letters following your `ds`. I assume that the `ds` is always at the start of a line and you have a multiline string to search for.

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/uuTlIT/1) and [ideone](http://ideone.com/aTg6yr) demos.

```
import re
str = '''ds000002_R2.0.2_raw.zip
ds000002_R2.0.3_raw.zip
ds000002_R2.0.4_raw.zip
ds000002_R2.0.5_raw.zip
ds000003_R2.0.0_raw.tgz
ds000003_R2.0.1_raw.tgz
ds002_raw_checksums.txt
ds003_models.tgz
ds113c_R1.0.0_sub-18.tgz
ds113c_R1.0.0_sub-20.tgz
ds113c_R1.0.0_sub-21.tgz
ds113b_raw.tgz
ds110.tgz'''
print(re.findall(r'(?mi)(?<=^ds)([a-z0-9]+)', str))
```

outputs `['000002', '000002', '000002', '000002', '000003', '000003', '002', '003', '113c', '113c', '113c', '113b', '110']`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
(?<=ds)(.*?)(?=[^0-9A-Fa-f])
```

results:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIGOO.jpg

Comment: Please post your image using the StackOverflow image uploader.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
ptrn = re.compile(r"ds(\d+).*")
ptrn.findall(strn)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `ds([0-9A-Za-z]+)` with `findall()` function from `re`, as both `_` and `.` don't belong to character class `[0-9A-Za-z]` the group pattern match will end at `_` or `.`:

```
import re
re.findall(r'ds([0-9A-Za-z]+)', 'ds000002_R2.0.2_raw.zip')
#['000002']

re.findall(r'ds([0-9A-Za-z]+)', 'ds000002.zip')
#['000002']

re.findall(r'ds([0-9A-Za-z]+)', 'ds113b_raw.tgz')
#['113b']
```

Comment: i have updated my question a bit. Can you please advise?

Comment: You can expand the character class from pure digits to alpha numeric `[0-9A-Za-z]` case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<=ds)\d+[a-z]?
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sElqQg/2